# Does gRPC perform the resource cleanup in .Net when you don't explicitly?

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, resource-cleanup

I have a gRPC server and multiple gRPC clients being created in different processes. Where should the gPRC network resources be cleaned up?

Current gRPC documentation states in low-frequency situations, let gRPC take care of it.

```
// My current client code to clean up resources:
channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50051", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
client = new HpcService.HpcServiceClient(channel);
// client api calls to server
... 
channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
client = null;
```

When I take over the resource clean up, the code is slower(~30%) and resource utilization(~10%) goes up.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "taking over the network resource cleanup". Generally, you should create a single (or a small number of) channel and reuse it for as many calls as possible. Creating (and shutting down) a channel is expensive, while invoking a call is comparatively cheap.

Comment: Good points.  I will be using it in AWS Lambda, there will not be concurrency and a call will be made every 10 to 15 minutes at most taking about 15 to 30 seconds to complete.  When I did perform some resource clean up it kept the function open noticeably longer (+10%). Thanks,